# ListView row styling - left aligned text, and right-aligned icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

I'm trying to get ListView row to look like the following:

```
| Text-Text-Text                        <ImageButton> |
```

With the imagebutton snapped to the right edge. How can I do this? Here's the current layout code I'm using. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layercontainer"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#699">
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="left">
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YO HOW SI IT GOESSDA" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="right">
   <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/trash" />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My code currently produces this:
[image: grrr]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Step #1: Use a `RelativeLayout` base.

Step #2: Put your `ImageButton` as having `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Step #3: Put your `TextView` has having `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, `android:layout_toLeftOf="..."` (where `...` is the ID of your `ImageButton`), and perhaps some other `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` value for vertical alignment

Comment: Hey! It worked! Thanks a bunch. I've never really used RelativeLayout before, so I didn't think of using them.

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet provides an example of how to create a ListView row that has some text (horizontally left-aligned, via `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`), and an icon (horizontally right-aligned via `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`), and all vertically centred (`android:layout_centerVertical="true"`).

It renders as follows (YMMV, depending on global styles):

[image: Rendering of code example]

There is also a commented-out additional icon that can be placed to the left of the right-most icon; remove the XML comment tags to enable.

Here is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="6dp">
    <!-- Note: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" set to ensure that
     OnItemClickListener works by ensuring constituent controls do not take focus -->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_list_item_row_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="My List Item Text"
        />

    <!-- This can be uncommented to add another button 

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_additional_icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_additional_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon_additional_icon" />

    -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon_additional_icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_right_aligned_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```