# How to show Android Right-aligned ListItem data without overlapping the scrollbar?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, listviewitem

I've basically the same thing as [ListView row styling - left aligned text, and right-aligned icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307655/align-layout-to-the-right-in-a-listview-row) : a listview with listitems in it that are right-aligned:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_name" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:text="0x0 0s"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_value" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and it works fine.. .except that the list_item_value text is obscured by the scrollbar. There's plenty of blank space between the names and values, scooting all the values to the left a little would be fine, but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting `android:layout_marginRight` on `list_item_value`. Try a value like 10dp or so - just to get a feel, then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that works; is there a way to set it equal to the scrollbar's width plus a couple more dp?

Comment: If that doesn't work, padding might help as well. Also, remember that the scrollbar is not always visible starting from 2.2 .